# Is the answer correct?

Tags: trigonometry

I had to simplify it: 
$$
\cos^2(\pi+x)+\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)=-\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=-(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))=-1.
$$ 
My answer turned out to be wrong. Could someone point out where is the mistake?

Comment: How can something that is clearly positive equal $-1$?

Comment: There is more than one mistake: $\cos^2(\pi+x)$ does not equal $-\cos^2 x$ and $\cos^2(\pi/2+x)$ does not equal $-\sin^2x$.

Comment: Very important.  If $a=-b $ then $a^2\ne -b^2$.  Instead $a^2=(-b)^2=b^2$.  $\cos^2 (whatever the heck) \ge 0$ while $-\cos^2(who knows what)\le 0$ so your answer can't possible ever be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\cos(\pi+x) = \cos \pi \cos x - \sin \pi \sin x = -\cos x 
$$
and 
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right) = \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \cos x - \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \sin x = -\sin x. 
$$
So 
$$ 
\cos^2(\pi+x)+\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right) 
= \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x =1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$cos(x) $ is negative in $2nd $ and $3rd$ quadrant , but $cos^2(x)$ is positive everywhere, so the answer should be $1$ as $$cos^2(\pi +x)=(cos(\pi+x))^2=(-cos(x))^2=cos^2(x)$$similarly$$cos^2({\pi\over 2}+x)=(cos({\pi\over 2}+x))^2=(-sin(x))^2=sin^2(x)$$and $$cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$\cos^2(\pi+x)+\cos^2[(\pi/2)+x]=(\cos\pi \cos x -\sin\pi \sin x)^2+[\cos(\pi/2)\cos x -\sin(\pi/2)\sin x ]^2=(-\cos x)^2+(-\sin x)^2=1$

Answer (score 0):

Although $\cos (\pi +x)=-\cos (x) $ and $\cos (\frac {\pi}2+ x)=-\sin (x)$ are absolutely true, $(-\cos (x))^2=-\cos^2 (x) $ and $(-\sin (x))^2=-\sin^2 (x) $ are absolutely false.